How to distinguish between silicon and boron with simple equipment?
I have a piece of brittle material and some smaller shards. It has metallic luster and quite low density (no bubbles inside the bulk).It shows no signs of corrosion despite being held at moist air for years, and it is inert to acid as well. It looks exactly like silicon in the pictures found by searching the internet.
At least one allotrope of boron looks exactly the same and has exactly the same density (for all practical purposes).
What tests can I easily do at home to identify this substance?
Assuming it is mostly silicon, can I also test its purity to some degree, say more or less than 95% pure?

Boron is a metal. Silicon is not. Even heavily doped silicon is not as conductive as a metal.

@JonCuster Is it easy to measure conductivity?

@JonCuster OK, I wanted to make some snarky remark here, but let's just say it's not a metal.

@JonCuster Check the electrical resistivity of B ($~\pu{10^6 Ω⋅m}$, ref), and Si ($\pu{2.3E3 Ω⋅m}$, ref) the diagonal down vs. for instance $\pu{15.87 nΩ⋅m}$ (Ag), or $\pu{26.5 nΩ⋅m}$ (Al).  Though the values may vary a bit (polymorph in question, relative orientation of the measurement vs crystalline coordinates), both B and Si about between "true metals" and "true non-metals".

@Mithoron Are the metallic shiny forms of boron tricky to produce? Why do you think all the (commonly encountered) allotropes are black?

OK, I checked a bit and it could be rather grey than black, but I think it may be a matter of impurities. There's also brown amorphous... I still think pure crystal should be black, though.

Why not a simple flame test? Strongly heat a small sample in an oxidizing flame, to convert some of the small sample to the oxide. If the flame appears green, that is due to boron. And the simple boron flame test can be used on the oxidized sample.

For silicon, Wikipedia reports a Mohs' hardness of 6.5 (property box of ref), and for boron one of about 9.5 (property box of ref).  On field trips, colleagues of geology/mineralogy/earth sciences sometimes carry a kit of reference tips to check if a sample can be scratched, or not:

(image credit https://www.mineralab.com, recycled from here)
The same Wikipedia article includes a list which assigns porcelain a hardness of 7. Hence if such a kit isn't accessible to you, silicon would be too soft to scratch porcelain, while boron surely would.  Which comes close to performing a streak test (does a sample leave a streak on unglazed porcelain of Mohs 6.5 to 7, and if so, is it colored the same/different to the apparent color of the sample):

(image credit https://geology.com/)
Neither scratch, nor streak test will quantify impurities in the sample, nor what they are.

It has lower mohs hardness than polished flint (7).

"It" referring to the sample? Well, there is not much left for a check at home. Neither B, nor Si reacts quickly with acid (thought because green flames of flame tests of borates). However some scrap yards use portable EDX guns (example) where one expects Si to show well. (If there were many grains of the sample, a quick discern were powder XRD -- because, lattice constants aside, only Si occurs with a cubic unit cell.  But one finds such machine only  in research labs.)

The easiest way is to   find someone with an electron microscope and ask them to please do an EDAX measurement. I would have done it for free when I was working in the lab. It is also possible it might be something else.

@jimchmst A science fair (or similar "open door" event) of a chemistry / physics department equally can be an occasion. Instead of magnifying for the nth time a fly (which can be interesting on its own), for multiple times the analytics group put coins (old penny vs new penny), rings, bracelets into the electron microscope; instructive.

@Buttonwood Yes, "It" refers to my sample. Quartz (flint is a form of quartz) is 7 by definition, so why not use this instead of porcelain.

Is it worth grinding a small amount in a mortar and reacting with sodium hydroxide or sulfur (I know the danger of $\ce{H2S}$ )? Could these reactions help with estimating the purity?

A physics answer would be IR transmission spectroscopy.  It's surprisingly hard to find spectra of boron online, but Wikipedia quotes a lowest bandgap of 1.6 eV (β-R phase) compared to 1.12 eV for Si.
I've got access to an FTIR so it would be quite easy to put the sample in that. Of course it would be far easier if it was a thin flat polished piece - I have access to the kit to do that as well.
Assuming you don't, that 1.6 eV corresponds to about 775 nm, barely into the IR.  A silicon camera sensor can see at that wavelength, though cameras generally have IR-reducing ("blocking", but they have some transmission) filters.  If you have a camera that can see the IR LED on a remote control clearly, and you cover it with a very thin (sub-mm but I'd polish it to around a hundred µm) piece of boron, you might be able to see the LED through it.
The other phases would transmit even a bit of red light in very thin pieces.
Si is most commonly seen as wafer pieces, but I've never seen a boron wafer.
Of course because it's so hard, I'd probably notice how much longer it took to polish than Si,  using diamond polishing materials (and even more so if I used SiC for rough grinding)
